# Read .net pajek file using python igraph library

Tags: python, igraph

I am trying to load a .net file using python igraph library. Here is the sample code:

```
import igraph
g = igraph.read("s.net",format="pajek")
```

But when I tried to run this script I got the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "demo.py", line 2, in <module>
g = igraph.read('s.net',format="pajek")
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\igraph\__init__.py", line 3703, in read
return Graph.Read(filename, *args, **kwds)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\igraph\__init__.py", line 2062, in Read
return reader(f, *args, **kwds)
igraph._igraph.InternalError: Error at .\src\foreign.c:574: Parse error in Pajek
file, line 1 (syntax error, unexpected ARCSLINE, expecting VERTICESLINE), Parse error
```

Kindly provide some hint over it.

Answer (score 2):

Either your file is not a regular Pajek file or igraph's Pajek parser is not able to read this particular Pajek file. (Writing a Pajek parser is a bit of hit-and-miss since the Pajek file format has no formal specification). If you send me your Pajek file via email, I'll take a look at it.

**Update**: you were missing the `*Vertices` section of the Pajek file. Adding a line like `*Vertices N` (where `N` is the number of vertices in the graph) resolves your problem. I cannot state that this line is mandatory in Pajek files because of lack of formal specification for the file format, but all the Pajek files I have seen so far included this line so I guess it's pretty standard.

Comment: Thanks @Tamas. I have just sent you the .net pajek files with username quamar niyaz @ gmail.com. Kinly have a look over it.

Comment: Thanks @Tamas, I have checked it by doing this but I think there is an issue with the file format. But the second file runs well by adding 
*Vertices N.